# Android call PHP with HTTP-GET

Tags: php, android, http, url, http-post

My question is: How to call a php with HttpPost?

```
 final HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
final HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("www.example.de/mySkript.php");
final ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param1", "value1"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param2", "value2"));

httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
final HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

We found this...but we don't want to send Parameters/Values to the PHP because our PHP is counting +1 if you call it through the URL. Any code for just call the PHP?

Thank you :)

edit:
The PHP is:

```
<?php
$userdatei = fopen ("test.txt","r");
$zeile = fgets($userdatei, 500);
$zeile++;
fclose($userdatei);

$schreiben = fopen ("test.txt","w");
fwrite($schreiben, $zeile);
fclose($schreiben);
?>
```

And Use this Code:

```
    public static HttpResponse hitUrl(String url) {
      try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));
        return response;
      } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
      }
    }
```

And call it with:

```
hitUrl("http://example.de/test.php");
```

Is this right?

Comment: "counting +1"..can you explain that further? why not make another PHP script like "example.de/api.php"?

Comment: @redreggae Our PHP ist counting the Views. So if you visit www.example.com/test.php the PHP writes in a TextFile the number of views.

Comment: OK but why you don't make another entry point for Android like "example.de/api.php" where it doesn't count? You can't run PHP on command line from another machine.

Comment: so what I want is just call this URL: www.example.com/test.php but not in a WebView...how to do this?

Comment: @redreggae What do you mean with: You can't run PHP on command line from another machine?

Comment: `HttpClient` is not `WebView`!? So `HttpClient` is the way to go. On the same machine you could run a php script like `passthru("/usr/bin/php /path/to/script.php");`

Comment: @redreggae For what? The PHP is working correctly when I open it on my Computer with Firefox/Chrome and it's counting +1

Comment: so what do you mean by "just call the PHP"? It's not clear what you are trying to do. If you don't want the parameters than uncomment the line `httppost.setEntity..`

Comment: @redreggae Instead of opening www.example.com/test.php via the WebView I'd like to "open" it via HttpClient(Background) without adding any Values/Parametes.

Comment: @redreggae I've updated the Code...may you know what I mean :D

Answer (score 0):

You need to make HTTP GET request to your server, you can use something like:

```
public static HttpResponse hitUrl(String url) {
  try {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));
    return response;
  } catch (Exception e) {
    Log.("[GET REQUEST]", "Network exception", e);
    return null;
  }
}
```

I can also recommend AQuery library for this server asynchronous calls:

http://code.google.com/p/android-query/

Comment: Check the response object, maybe you call bad URL? Or your PHP script crashes? Try to post also your PHP code.

Comment: It looks fine. How about HttpResponse? What is the http status code? When you add echo to your PHP code, can you read its output from response on Android?