# How can I integrate php with Android app?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

Hi I am very new to Android Programming. I was trying to make a login/ Registration app in Android. I created php script to connect and modify my database. Following is the code I wrote for the app by looking at a tutorial, but when I try to run it I get some errors. Can someone please tell me where I am going wrong.

```
    public class RegisterActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    EditText username;
    EditText password;
    EditText emailid;
    EditText phonenumber;

    // url to create new product
    private static String url_register_user = "http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/project/2013/271/g1327139/webapp/php%20script/index.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register_user);

        // Edit Text
        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reg_username);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reg_password);
        emailid = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reg_emailid);
        phonenumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reg_mobilenumber);

        // Create button
        Button register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register);

        // button click event
        register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // creating new product in background thread
                new RegisterNewUser().execute();
            }
        });
    }


    /**
     * Background Async Task to Create new product
     * */

     private class RegisterNewUser extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(RegisterActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Registering User..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Registering user
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            String userName = username.getText().toString();
            String passWord = password.getText().toString();
            String emailId = emailid.getText().toString();
            String phoneNumber = phonenumber.getText().toString();
            String register = "register";

            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", register));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", userName));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", passWord));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("emailid", emailId));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phonenumber", phoneNumber));

            // getting JSON Object
            // Note that create product url accepts POST method
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeServiceCall(url_register_user,
                    2, params);

            // check log cat fro response
            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

            // check for success tag
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully created product

                    // closing this screen
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // failed to create product
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once done
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.register_user, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

These are the error I get when I try to register a new user.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at 
com.example.pubcrawl.app.RegisterActivity$RegisterNewUser.doInBackground(RegisterActivity.java:113)
        at com.example.pubcrawl.app.RegisterActivity$RegisterNewUser.doInBackground(RegisterActivity.java:74)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)


05-26 15:20:51.511    8766-8766/com.example.pubcrawl.app E/WindowManager﹕      android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.pubcrawl.app.RegisterActivity has leaked     window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{42ba7588 V.E..... R......D 0,0-    1026,288} that was originally added here
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:456)
            at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:267)
            at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
             at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:288)
             at `enter code     here`com.example.pubcrawl.app.RegisterActivity$RegisterNewUser.onPreExecute(RegisterActivity.j    ava:86)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
            at com.example.pubcrawl.app.RegisterActivity$1.onClick(RegisterActivity.java:64)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4633)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19330)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-26 15:20:57.607    8766-9420/com.example.pubcrawl.app I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID:     8766 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Line 86, whatever that is.  Please read your exceptions.

Comment: wrong question: android couldn't care less what's running on the server. it could be a trained hamster pointing at a letter board with an OCR system spitting out the html. your question should be "how to do an http request from android"

Comment: Yes @MarcB I agree. I am not really sure how to do http request from android

Answer (score 1):

You could do this

**JSONParser class**

```
public class JSONParser
{

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

public JSONParser() {

}

public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method, List<NameValuePair> params)
{

    try
    {
        if (method == "POST")
        {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }
        else if (method == "GET")
        {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }

    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (ClientProtocolException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    try
    {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    }
    catch (JSONException e)
    {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    return jObj;
}
}
```

**RegisterActivity**

```
public class RegisterActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

EditText username;
EditText password;
EditText emailid;
EditText phonenumber;

// url to create new product
private static String url_register_user = "http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/project/2013/271/g1327139/webapp/php%20script/index.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register_user);

    // Edit Text
    username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reg_username);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reg_password);
    emailid = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reg_emailid);
    phonenumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reg_mobilenumber);

    // Create button
    Button register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register);

    // button click event
    register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // creating new product in background thread
            new RegisterNewUser().execute();
        }
    });
}


/**
 * Background Async Task to Create new product
 * */

 private class RegisterNewUser extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(RegisterActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Registering User..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Registering user
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        String userName = username.getText().toString();
        String passWord = password.getText().toString();
        String emailId = emailid.getText().toString();
        String phoneNumber = phonenumber.getText().toString();
        String register = "register";

        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", register));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", userName));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", passWord));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("emailid", emailId));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phonenumber", phoneNumber));

        // getting JSON Object
        // Note that create product url accepts POST method
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeServiceCall(url_register_user,
                "POST", params);

        // check log cat fro response
        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

        // check for success tag
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // successfully created product

                // closing this screen
                finish();
            } else {
                // failed to create product
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once done
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.register_user, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest putting a breakpoint in your code and stepping through it.

My memory tells me that the  makeServiceCall should have the params URL, METHOD and PARAMS. Is your method actually called 2?

If not put a put a breakpoint in and find out where the error is at.

Also, check this question out [Android call PHP with HTTP-GET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15322940/android-call-php-with-http-get).

There is a massive amount of websites returned if you look for "calling PHP scrip when developing android application"